# How do I make my very simple website look right at different resolutions?

Tags: html, css

My very simple website (see code below) is based on CSS/HTML.

It looks just perfect at `1600 x 900` but if I change that the site gets really messy.

How do I make it look right at different resolutions?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/> 
        <title>Dogma Hostil</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="titulo">
    <p>Dogma Hostil</p>
    </div>
    <div id="raya"><p>___________</p></div>
    <div id="cita">
    <p>Todo comienzo tiene su encanto</p>
    <a id="author" href="http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Wolfgang_von_Goethe">Goethe</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#titulo {
position: absolute;
left: 17%;
top: 17%;
z-index:1;
display: inline-block;
}

#titulo p {
color: black;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 1000%;
z-index: 2;
display: inline-block;
}



#titulo p:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #00ff78, 0 0 70px    #00ff78, 0 0 80px #00ff78, 0 0 100px #00ff78, 0 0 150px #00ff78, 0 0 299px #000000, 0 0 5px #000000;
  z-index: 3;
  }

#raya {
position: absolute;
left:16%;
top:20%;
z-index: -1;
}

#raya p {
color:black;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 1000%;
z-index: 0;

}

#cita{
position: absolute;
left: 80%;


 }

#cita p {
color:black;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 100%;
 }

 #author {
position: absolute;
left:78%;
top:65%;
color: black;
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;


 }
```

Comment: There are couple of ways to make an element be aligned center. But the point is, for the `left` property: the percentage refers to the width of the containing block. And it would be different on various sizes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a pretty broad question, but it has a simple answer you might not expect since you are new to HTML and CSS. I've given you an answer that ought to give you a great place to start searching for what you need to learn to make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first lesson.  If you use Absolute positioning, unless you absolutely (no pun intended) know what you're doing, you will likely break your design when resizing.

You want fluid and/or responsive layouts, these are layouts that adjust to different sizes well.

Here's a good article to get you started.

http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3-9122768

Even if you want a fixed-sized layout, you still have to take into account that the browser may be different sizes.  So you need to use automatic margins, unless you plan to make everything bound to the top left corner of your browser window.

For instance, it's super easy to center block level elements (such as divs), you just set the left and right margin to auto.

```
#content { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Also, Use the natural flow layout of the browser to your advantage.  Most things base their positions (margins, borders, padding, etc..) based on their parent element.  So by using proper padding or margins, you can position things where you want them, and they'll automatically re-lay themselves out in the right place based on that parent.

Comment: Thanks men! Article and comment are very helpfull, I will learn about fluid/responsive/ adaptative them!

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing one of the chief difficulties in "web/mobile design" today...

Your design is made using mostly `static` design principles.

### Use `responsive` / `adaptive` or `fluid` ( a.k.a. `liquid` ) design principles:

Responsive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Adaptive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_web_design

Fluid/Liquid: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24406/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-fluid-and-responsive-design

---

**Go see examples of the top four design philosophies being used today, and how they compare:**

- http://liquidapsive.com/

...there you can switch between them real-time, play with the differences yourself, and learn by example.

---

The switch to `responsive` design especially is a major era change in "web design" and its philosophies. It is not taught widely enough, but is not very difficult to learn.

"Superficial" changes like adjusting from `px` to `em` or `%` in CSS are not going to really help you. Today, design must take phone, tablet, and low-resolution & and high-resolution desktops into account from the start. Best of luck to you as you look into `responsive` / `adaptive` and `fluid` design.

Comment: hi! Thank you very illustrative,now I know what I need, can you help me with a book, website, or anything that help me learn how to make a fluid/responsive/adaptative web design? That will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use percentages or try to add a 100% description to the body tag

Comment: I've already tried with "em" with the same result, if you could be more specific will be great!